# Disabling an Image button from being clicked, but maintain its class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On a pool scoreboard webpage I have created, I need to disable the add score buttons from being clicked when a player has reached their target (raceTo). However, it is all in an update panel and when I disable the add score buttons and display the 'Winner/Loser' image, it knocks all the alignment out on the page. This seems to be because I do: `btnaddFramePlayer1.Enabled="false"` and it disables the class within that button. How can I disable the score buttons from being clicked but maintain the rest of the buttons attributes?

```xml
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlAddFramePlayer1" style="margin-top:0px;" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnaddFramePlayer1" eventname="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnaddFramePlayer2" eventname="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="BtnPlayer1Dishes" eventname="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="BtnPlayer2Dishes" eventname="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="BtnPlayer1ReverseDishes" eventname="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="BtnPlayer2ReverseDishes" eventname="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="btnUndo" eventname="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>   
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnaddFramePlayer1" runat="server" class="scores" ImageUrl="~/files/images/scores/scoreBlue0.png" visible="True" OnClick="btnaddFramePlayer1_Click" />
            <p style="font-size:0.4em;"><asp:Image ID="imgCongrats1" runat="server" class="result" ImageUrl="~/files/images/congrats.gif" visible="false" /><asp:Image ID="imgUnlucky1" runat="server" class="result" ImageUrl="~/files/images/unlucky.gif" visible="false" /></p>
            <p style="font-size:0.4em;"><asp:ImageButton ID="BtnPlayer1Dishes" class="dishscores" OnClick="btnaddFrameAndDishPlayer1_Click" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/files/images/scores/breakDish0.png" ></asp:ImageButton><asp:ImageButton ID="BtnPlayer1ReverseDishes" class="dishscores"  runat="server" OnClick="btnaddFrameAndReverseDishPlayer1_Click" ImageUrl="~/files/images/scores/reverseBreakDish0.png" ></asp:ImageButton></p>
        </ContentTemplate>  
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB.Net

```
    If session("raceTo") > "0" And session("raceTo") = Session(“score1”) Then
         imgCongrats1.visible="true"
         imgUnlucky2.visible="true"
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

So, assume I have a button with the bootstrap class "btn", and also have a custom class for that button.

So, say this:

```
        <h4>Above Button</h4>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Test Button"
            CssClass="btn myshadow"
            style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px"
            />
        <h4>Below Button</h4>
```

Now, for the asp: Button above click event, I disable the button.

Hence this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Button1.Enabled = False


End Sub
```

So, the result is this:

[image]

So, an enable, or disable of the button? It should not affect the position or sizing. I would check your button class and CSS style - since I suspect it has some "a" for an active or used link.

As above shows, enabling or disabling the button does not seem to affect the position of the button. Now hiding? That is of course a vast different matter.

So, you should be able to disable buttons, and they should not affect the layout or position. You may well have to tweak the CSS used for that button.

And you can add a disabled part to the CSS for that button.

Say this for my button class:

```
<style>
    .myshadow
    {box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px 0px gray}
    .myshadow {border-radius:10px}
    .myshadow:hover {background-color:#789eca;transition: 0.5s;}
    .myshadow {border:solid;border-color:lightgray;border-width:.1em}

    .myshadow:disabled
    {background-color:yellow}
</style>
```

So, now the effect is this:

[image]

So, once again, disabling a button? It does not appear to change the layout, and in fact you can add to your CSS the :disabled attribute that allows custom styling when you do disable the button.

Either way, I not seeing the button class "go away" or being removed.

Of course, there is a Mount Everest of a difference here between disabling a button as opposed to hiding, or setting visible = false which of course will cause a layout change.

And using an image button produces the same results.

Hence this:

```
        <h4>Above Button</h4>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="btn myshadow"
            ImageUrl="Content/swap2.png"
            OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"
            
            />
        <h4>Below Button</h4>
```

And the result is this:

[image]